# Glassfish: NoClassDefFoundError while deploying the application

Tags: java, ant, google-analytics, glassfish, google-analytics-firebase

Not sure how to fix this issue. I have all the required jars declared under Ant's `build.xml` and added to the app's classpath.

```
ERROR ContextLoader                  - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1906)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:962)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
```

Could not find any specific compile-time or runtime settings in the build.xml? Would it make sense to move runtime jars to `${GLASSFISH_HOME}/modules/` folder

Comment: Could you please add your ant build script? Maybe you have glassfish scoped so it's not visible in the final version of your app?

Comment: I have a huge ant file. It wouldn't be possible to paste it here.

Comment: You could always use an external website like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).